# migrating from one node private network to real-like multi node using Ganache-cli

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I made a Dapp on a local node using ganache-cli as my eth blockcahin and i want to simulate a real main-net.

A real main-net  where i can connect with multiple nodes and these nodes share the mining process and get rewarded gas for doing so. 
I admit maybe i am missing something, but i really need to get this.

Is there any way of doing so,

Comment: Why not use the testnets? Otherwise have a look at this: https://capgemini.github.io/blockchain/ethereum-docker-compose/ or that https://medium.com/mercuryprotocol/how-to-create-your-own-private-ethereum-blockchain-dad6af82fc9f

Comment: The test net require me to have ether right ? and i don't really know where to get that, and i will look into those links